# Using Redis clusters and transactions

Tags: php, laravel, redis, lumen, predis

While using Redis cluster I get the following error:

```
Cannot use 'MULTI' with redis-cluster.
```

With the just the following call:

```
Redis::multi();
```

Is there a way to ensure data integrity across the clusters without the use of transactions, since that is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redis doesn't support transaction, if keys are located on different slots/nodes.

If you have to store your data in a cluster, you must ensure all keys related to your transaction are stored on a single slot. You can use [hash tag](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) to do that.

Then you can take the node holding the slot as a single Redis instance, and run transaction on that node.

Comment: Is this still true for Redis cluster? Does Redis still not support a transaction involving keys on multiple nodes?

Comment: As far as I understood, Redis only allows a transaction involving multiple keys belonging to same hash slot.

Comment: @Siddhant YES, it's still true that Redis only allow transaction involving keys belonging to the same hash slot. If keys are located on multiple slots, you cannot execute transaction on these keys.